# Opening two websites in two browsers with one button?

Tags: windows

I am looking to open chrome with one website, and the same website in a separate incognito chrome window at the same time.

Is there an easy shortcut for this using notepad/desktop shortcut/etc, so that one button push opens both in separate instances?

(use abc.com for the domain example)

Comment: please share what you did? Here is not a reception. Before ask a question please let us know more info about your problem such as your IDE, development language..etc

Answer (score 1):

make a batch file and run it from desktop 
Put this in  batch file

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -incognito "http://google.com"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "http://google.com" 


[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/writing-windows-batch-script/][1]
```

Comment: thanks!  it seems to only want to open the first window and not the second (unless i already have chrome open in which case it did open it into a new tab, but that wouldnt serve the purpose of the op.)

Comment: i also found that when i close one of the windows it opened it will then immediately open the second window that it was supposed to open simultaneously.